What does "滲むように" mean by itself?
日向は振り返ると、滲むように微笑んだ。
The narration adds this after one character points something funny. The character turns around ans laughs. But what does 滲む actually mean here? "As if to reveal himself?"

This is not a common expression but rather a unique poetic/literary expression, so we can only speculate about its meaning. The surrounding context is also very important.
If I need to imagine its meaning based on the given excerpt and the basic nuance of 滲む (to blur/seep), it could be interpreted as a gentle smile slowly spreading across his face.
